# Find a compact smooth curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following question.

Find a compact smooth curve $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the following property or give a counter example. For all $a \in C$, there is some neighborhood $U$ containing $a$ and functions $f,g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that either any point in $U$ lies on $C$ if and only if $f(x) = y$ and $g(x)=z$ or $f(y) = x$ and $g(y)=z$.

My textbook says a set $S$ is a smooth curve if $S$ is connected and $\forall a \in S$ has neighborhood $N$ such that $S \cap N$ is the graph of $C^1$.

Can anyone help me with this?? I have no guess if there is such curve or not!

Comment: Hints: Could you do this in two dimensions? Closed loops are often compact.

Comment: I was thinking a circle would work in two dimension. But I realized that the question asks in three dimension. So is a circle in three dimension works??

Comment: Correct. If you are a little bit careful in how you place the circle, it will work in 3D also. A thing you should observe is that the possibility of $x$ and $y$ being locally functions of $z$ is not allowed. So no matter where you are, all nearby points must have distintict $x$-coordinates or distinct $y$-coordinates.